# C++ Recursion how to use if statement in while

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, while-loop, codeblocks

I was doing a recursion to find the factorial of a number, when I write the function everything goes fine:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int factorialfinder(int x){
if(x==1){
    return 1;
}else{
    return x * factorialfinder(x-1);
}
}

int main()
{
int x;
cout << "Please enter a number for the factorial finder " << endl;
cin >> x;
cout << "The factorial of " << x << " is " << factorialfinder(x) << endl << endl;
cout << "Enter another number for the factorial finder " << endl;


while(x > -1){
    cin >> x;
    cout << "The factorial of " << x << " is " << factorialfinder(x) << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter another number for the factorial finder " << endl;
}

}
```

but I wanted to add a if statement about if x is = 0 or <= -1 then it will show a error message but I cant do this in while loop by using if it will cause error and it will auto terminate my program why? :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int factorialfinder(int x){
if(x==1){
    return 1;
}else{
    return x * factorialfinder(x-1);
}
}

int main()
{
int x;
cout << "Please enter a number for the factorial finder " << endl;
cin >> x;
cout << "The factorial of " << x << " is " << factorialfinder(x) << endl << endl;
cout << "Enter another number for the factorial finder " << endl;


while(x > -1){
    cin >> x;
    if(x = 0 || x <= -1){
    cout << "Please enter a proper value to find the factorial";}
    else{
    cout << "The factorial of " << x << " is " << factorialfinder(x) << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter another number for the factorial finder " << endl;}
}

}
```

Comment: I wanted to show "Please enter a proper value to find the factorial" if the user enter a value that are = 0 or <= -1

Comment: `x=0` Oh no... an assignment in place of a comparison, should be `==` instead. Also, factorial of 0 is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is wrong, you are using an assignment operator `=` instead of comparison `==`

You need to write this :

```
 if(x == 0 || x <= -1)
```

You can better write it as `if(x<=0)` as Karsten Koop Pointed out

Comment: `x` is an `int`, so this could be simplified to `x<=0`

Comment: @gamesymbol Btw 0 has a valid factorial.